# How to change ubuntu version to earlier one on wsl?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

everyone! I'm a new learner and I need your help!
Lately, I installed wsl on my Windows for my tasks, it's the latest version of Ubuntu on it - 22.04. But at this moment I need to write bash scripts on Ubuntu 20.04 version, there are differences on how scripts run on different Ubuntu versions.

I see 2 ways of solving this problem. Or to change the version of ubuntu on wsl, or to connect to virtual box machine.

1. So, how do I return to an earlier version on wsl, if it is possible?
2. Or how do I enter from my wsl terminal to my ubuntu 20.04 in virtual machine (on Virtual Box)?
   Or maybe there is another solution, that I don't know.

Thank you in advance for your answers!)

Comment: I think you may be solving the problem in a rather cumbersome way. It's usually possible to write the bash scripts so that they work in both releases.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Really? Why? Then where do I get the answers? It's not that I'm not looking for them in other resources, but yet can't find what I need. I thought people who experienced this, could give an advice or help somehow.

Comment: This question should not be asked in stackoverflow, since here you should ask for help in the programming stuff

Comment: Ok, I will close it, as soon as I find out how)

Comment: It _would_ be about programming if you asked about how to make the bash script work in both 20.04 and 22.04 though. That would seem like the simplest and also less maintenance heavy solution to me.

Comment: @TedLyngmo ok, I see that's a better idea. I didn't know it is possible. I'll have a try.

Comment: @Helionthebus I rarely have to change my bash scripts because of an OS upgrade. If it happens, there's usually something I can add or make more generic in the script so that it works in the new release as well as in the old.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I see. Actually I experienced a little error in my new version with a script that worked in the old one. It worked, but also showed an error line. Well, I'm just a starter, so that seemed a problem to me. But now I understand that it can be solved, that it's not that big problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to write what I did to solve my problem.
After searching and reading about different ways to solve my problem, taking into account all the given advices here, I got to conclusion that the easiest way for me, to create a common folder on my host OS (aka Windows), which will be seen also from my virtual machine. This way I write, edit my tasks in that folder, then run and test both through wsl (which has ubuntu 22.04 on it) and through VM (with ubuntu 20.04 on it). So, at the same time I can learn of there are any differences between these Ubuntu versions.
Maybe this will be helpful to someone!